# Como eu faço para remover 3 caracteres especiais em uma variável string, usando regex?

Tags: c#, regex

Linguagem utilizada é c#, como faço para remover 3 caracteres especiais em uma variável string, usando `regex`?

> - exemplo: (11) 2134-2135
> - resultado esperado: 112132135